# How can I pass multiple params into a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
app.directive('testDir', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var abc=attr.testDir;
            var def=< The value zzz >
        }
    };
}])
```

I understand I can call this like:

```
<div test-dir='abcd'>xx</div>
```

What if I also needed to pass the parameter 'zzz'.  How can I pass more than one parameter to my directive?

Comment: What else are you trying to pass?

Comment: You can use the same attrs variable that was the answer to your last question.

Comment: I was thinking if for example I wanted to pass a height and a width parameter to the directive.

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple attributes. Your directive has access to all attributes used in the element:

```
<div my-directive arg-one='abcd', arg-two>xx</div>

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
      link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
          var abc=attr.argOne;
          var def=attr.argTwo;
      }
  };
});
```

Notice the change from `-` to camelCase. This is done by AngularJS.

Comment: So I could just pass a height and width by putting arg-height=60 and arg-width=99 inside the DIV ?  Would I need to enclose those in quotes and could they be in any position inside the div. I am a bit confused as would this not conflict with other things inside the DIV ?

Comment: I don't think it matters if you enclose them in quotes or not, but I'm sure it doesn't mess with the other attrs if you don't use obvious attributes (e.g. alt). Order doesn't matter for HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array like so

```
 <div test-dir='["abcd","zzz"]'>xx</div>
```

Then in your directive you can do

```
var abc = JSON.parse(attr.testDir); // = Array ["abcd","zzz"]
```